# SRP in methods that represent SQL queries

Tags: sql, vb.net, oop, design-patterns

I am working on an app that access a db and now I was wondering what is the best practice here.

Maybe is a stupid question, but then I want to make sure it is stupid:P

I have methods representing queries like this:

```
Public Function GetCellVposOfTransmitter(transmitter As VPos) As VPos
    Return (From position In Dc.VPos
            Join article In Dc.Art
            On position.ArtID Equals article.ArtID
            Where position.VID = transmitter.VID And position.Pos = transmitter.Pos And article.WGrp = 52 
            Select position).FirstOrDefault()
End Function

Public Function GetPressureTransmittersFromProcessId(processId As Integer) As IQueryable(Of VPos)
    Return From position In Dc.VPos
           Join article In Dc.Art
           On position.ArtID Equals article.ArtID
           Where position.SPos = 0 And position.VID = processId And article.WGrp = 33 
           Select position
End Function
```

In this case I call `GetPressureTransmittersFromProcessId` first to get a collection of devices associated to a given process and then for every returned item I call `GetCellVposOfTransmitter` to get the measuring cell built in each device.

Now every method has only one responsability and is so simple as possible, BUT I query twice the database, and in this case more, since I loop trough the collection and query each time.

I could write a method with a query that returns e.g. a `Dictionary(Of Vpos,Vpos)` that contains every device as key and the associated cell as value.
So I will query only once, but I am breaking (or I am not?) the SRP...

What is the best-practice here? I mean, what has priority here, code or server performance? My app will not be overload any server (lol), but is just to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you create a method that returns a different data view, you don't break SRP. The responsibility of the new method is different. Server performance is in first place here. If you worry about code duplication, you can chain you methods together. So for instance, let's say you want to write a method, replacing your loop and still use method GetPressureTransmittersFromProcessId somewhere else, you can do:

```
Public Function GetCellVposOfTransmittersFromProcessId(processId As Integer) As IQueryable(Of VPos)
    Return  From transmitter In GetPressureTransmittersFromProcessId(processId)
            Join position In Dc.VPos On transmitter position.VID Equals transmitter.VID And position.Pos Equals transmitter.Pos
            Join article In Dc.Art On position.ArtID Equals article.ArtID
            Where article.WGrp = 52 
            Select position
End Function
```